# Error upgrading libc6 on Debian Sid

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

Trying to upgrade Debian Sid I get the error

```
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.30-3_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libc6:i386 (2.30-2) ...

A copy of the C library was found in an unexpected directory:
  '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.30.so'
It is not safe to upgrade the C library in this situation;
please remove that copy of the C library or get it out of
'/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' and try again.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.30-3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new libc6:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../archives/libc6_2.30-3_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libc6:amd64 (2.30-2) ...

A copy of the C library was found in an unexpected directory:
  '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.30.so'
It is not safe to upgrade the C library in this situation;
please remove that copy of the C library or get it out of
'/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu' and try again.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.30-3_i386.deb (--unpack):
 new libc6:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.30-3_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.30-3_i386.deb
```

apt --fix-broken install is of no help, simply returning this error as well. Trying to upgrade again after this gives me

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.30-3) but 2.30-2 is installed
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.30-3) but 2.30-2 is installed
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

---

There is an open Debian bug report.
Bug ID [954915](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=954915)